# How to cancel Firestore Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I want to cancel Stream  which made by DocumentReference.snapshot().
But I can't do it. I just cancel StreamSubscription which listen it.
How to cancel this stream?

Comment: you can only `cancel()` the `StreamSubscription`